# How to add an id attribute to a html tag with a certain class using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a link with a class of `special` and I want to add an id attribute to it.

Only one element in my document will have this class at any one time (I may remove and add a new one at some point).

How would I add an id attribute to the element to change it from this:

```
<div class="special">
```

to this:

```
<div id="special-12345" class="special">
```

Answer (score 31):

Adding the attribute is easy:

```
$('.special').attr('id', 'your-id-value');
```

The more potentially problematic part will be ensuring that the id's you are adding are unique.

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
$('div.special').attr('id','your-id');
```

Comment: No i used 'div.special' rather than '.special' which is faster way to search a DOM element.

Answer (score 5):

```
$(".special").attr("id","special-" + (new Date()).getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add id with:

```
$('.special').attr('id', 'id-value');
```

Do you want change id?

```
$('.special').removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'id-value');
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't have the reputation to add a comment, but i believe it's benefitial enough for others searching for answer to state, that

```
attr();
```

Doesn't simply **add** the attribute but rather **sets** it. Important when there already is some set ID on the element.